# Which vector rotation is correct?

Tags: vectors, rotations

If my axis extends from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1), my candidate vector is (1,0,0), and I rotate the candidate vector about the axis for 120 degrees, what will be the location of the rotated vector?

According to [this link](https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/vector-rotation) it should be (-0.5, 0.86, 0).

According to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TggbcOrALMQ&ab_channel=%E5%A4%8Fsir%E7%B6%B2%E4%B8%8A%E6%95%99%E5%AE%A4) it should be (0, 1, 0).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should immediately see why it is not $(0, 1, 0)$ by imagining or sketching a quick diagram. To determine the exact value, consider that the rotation is entirely in the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General case**

If $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$, $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ define a plane of normal $\mathbf{\hat{w}} \equiv \frac{\mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}}{||\mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}||}$, the *counterclockwise rotation matrix* around $\mathbf{\hat{w}}$ is:

$$
\mathbf{R}(\theta,\mathbf{\hat{w}}) = \mathbf{I} + (\sin\theta)\mathbf{W} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{W}\cdot\mathbf{W}
$$

known as *Rodrigues' Rotation Formula*, where we define the matrices:

$$
\mathbf{I} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{W} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -w_3 & w_2 \\
w_3 & 0 & -w_1 \\
-w_2 & w_1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore, the matrix that rotates $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$ to the direction of $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ is nothing but $\mathbf{R}(\arccos(\mathbf{\hat{u}}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{v}}),\mathbf{\hat{w}})$.

---

**Specific case**

Since $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{w}} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, then:

$$
\mathbf{R} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\mathbf{R}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

which is what was wanted.